# adonis project is not build gives UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am trying to deploy adonis.js 5. It gives the following error

```
(node:1124904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /var/www/fb-project/api/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/package.json
at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:285:9)
at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:491:3)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:490:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:27)
at resolveFileName (/var/www/fb-project/api/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:29:39)
at resolveFrom (/var/www/fb-project/api/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:43:9)
at Object.module.exports [as default] (/var/www/fb-project/api/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:46:47)
at Object.resolveFrom (/var/www/fb-project/api/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/src/Helpers/resolveFrom.js:25:34)
at Application.resolveModule (/var/www/fb-project/api/node_modules/@adonisjs/application/build/src/Application.js:151:32)
```

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1124904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1124904) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

No clue whats wrong. It works in another server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ok issue was with node version. problem solved with node version 14.16.1